# Python3 Kraken Exchange Websockets AddOrder not working

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I'm trying to send orders through websockets, but I don't know how to receive the response from the websocket as to whether it was successful or not. The site (https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034936531-WebSocket-API-Trading-addOrder-and-cancelOrder) says that once the order had been sent, there will be a response outlining whether it was successful or not.

I'm just testing the addOrder with the following code:

```
async def test():
    async for ws in websockets.connect("wss://ws-auth.kraken.com/"):
        try:
            token = generate_token()
            request = {"event": "subscribe", "subscription": {"name": "addOrder", "token": token}}
            await ws.send(json.dumps(request))
            confirm_connection(await ws.recv())
            confirm_subscription(await ws.recv())
            volume = 0.0001
            leverage = 0
            ID = '12345'
            request = {'event': 'addOrder', 'token': token, 'reqid': ID, 'ordertype': 'market', 'type': 'buy', 'pair': "XBT/USD", 'volume': volume, 'userref': ID, 'validate': 1}
            resp1 = await ws.send(json.dumps(request))
            resp2 = await ws.recv()
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            continue
```

It connects to the websocket, makes a request for a test trade, sends that off. Then when I try to receive a response (line with resp2 = ...) it just says the following:

```
'{"errorMessage":"Public market data subscriptions are unavailable on this endpoint. Try ws.kraken.com","event":"subscriptionStatus","status":"error","subscription":{"name":"addOrder","token":"X"}}'
```

How are you supposed to receive the response as to whether Kraken received the trade request or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after some time, so this is for anyone else who has this issue.

There were no issues with websocket subscription, it was working as intended. Kraken does a weird thing where they send an error through the websocket, but it really is just a message and can be ignored. The websocket remains open and operational afterwards, so you just need to ignore the first response from the websocket.

Comment: Please consider providing more detailed steps you followed to reach to the root cause, so it will help future users. If there are any source code changes done, post them as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with kraken websockets addOrder, but I do have experience with kraken addOrder api and kraken ownTrades and openOrders websocket subscriptions.

I'm guessing here, but judging from the error message, it looks like the error message is a response to a previous websocket subscription call you made requesting to subscribe to a channel data feed (not sure which one though).

With websockets, upon connection, you should get a systemStatus response message. In it, it contains the status ("online" is what you want to check for).

Next, depending on the subscription, you may receive a snapshot message pertaining to that service if it's online. That message will contain recent trade fills (ownTrades subscription), or currently open order (openOrders subscription). I haven't touched individual asset pair subscriptions, but I'm guessing recent activity there will be communicated as well.

I have no idea if anything I've stated herein will help you, but I do know this will definitely help you...

Contact kraken support by logging into your kraken account and then click on Support. I always open a support ticket (no chat, etc.) so that I can provide them with as much detail as I can including what I'm doing, how I'm doing it, and all error messages I'm getting back from them.

To date, they have responded in less than 24 hours and they've always given me very specific answers to my questions (there have been many questions). Overall, I would rate their support minimally 4.5 out of 5 stars.

Good luck.

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.